# Oracle SQL - combine with negative or positive rounding adjustment value use Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
table_a
---------------------------
orderid,item,total_amount
---------------------------
1001,apple,10.00
1001,banana,5.00
1001,orange,8.00
1002,papaya,6.00
1002,water_melon,7.00

table_b
----------------------
orderid,total_payment
----------------------
1001,23.00
1002,13.00
    
table_c
-------------------
orderid,adjust
-------------------
1001,0.02
1002,-0.02
```

if table_c adjust is (+) positive will minus total_payment

```
result
---------------------
orderid,total_payment
1001,22.98
```

if table_c adjust is (-) negative will sum total_payment

```
result
---------------------
orderid,total_payment
1002,13.02
```

May i know how to use SQL to query result like this ?
the table_c adjust rounding for this only example, the value could be -.01,.02,-.03,.04,-.04

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what `table_a` has to do with your question.

You don't specify if there are multiple adjustments.  Assuming there is just one, then `left join` does what you want:

```
select b.*,
       b.total_payment - coalesce(c.adjust, 0) as adjusted_total_payment
from table_b b left join
     table_c c
     using (orderid);
```

If there could be multiple adjustments in `c` for a given `orderid`, then aggregate first:

```
select b.*,
       b.total_payment - coalesce(c.adjust) as adjusted_total_payment
from table_b b left join
     (select orderid, sum(adjust) as adjust
      from table_c c
      group by orderid
     ) c
     using (orderid);
```

Comment: Missing the second argument in `coalesce` (probably 0)?

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic part you learned in middle school (when you must have been 13 to 15 years old), you just forgot it. If you must subtract `0.02` when `x = 0.02`, and you must add `0.02` when `x = -0.02`, this is the same as adding `-x`, the *negative* of the number `x`. (Which raises questions about how this was modeled; why aren't decrease adjustments stored as negative numbers, and increase adjustments as positive numbers? Whoever decided to store it this way wasn't thinking clearly at the time.)

The coding is slightly more interesting. From the data you posted, it seems that `table_a` is the base data, `table_b` is not a table at all (it shouldn't be anyway - if it is, that is an exceptionally poor data model) but the result of an elementary aggregate query against `table_a`, and `table_c` holds additional information that may apply to some (but not necessarily all) orders. And your task is to aggregate the data from `table_a` and `table_c` together.

You can do that if you first perform `union all` of `table_a` and `table_c`, but just with a little bit of care, since you must "add" `-adjust` from `table_c` (with the minus sign in front). Then it goes back to a trivial `GROUP BY` and `SUM` query. Like this:

```
select orderid, sum(amount) as adjusted_total_payment
from   (
         select orderid,  total_amount as amount from table_a
         union all
         select orderid, -adjustment   as amount from table_c 
                     --  ^ -- notice the minus sign
       )
group  by orderid;
```

Note that this will work whether there are no adjustments, exactly one, or multiple adjustments for any given `orderid`.

The more interesting remaining issue is, after you generate a bill for your customer, presumably the "adjustment" should be cleared out. How are you doing that? But, obviously, that interesting question has nothing to do with what you asked in this thread.